# Importing the same modules in different files

Tags: python, import

Supposing I have written a set of classes to be used in a python file and use them in a script (or python code in a different file). Now both the files require a set of modules to be imported. Should the import be included only once, or in both the files ?

File 1 : **my_module.py**.

```
import os

class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self,PATH):
        self.list_of_directories = os.listdir(PATH)
```

File 2 :

```
import os
import my_module

my_module.m = myclass("C:\\User\\John\\Desktop")

list_ = m.list_of_directories

print os.getcwd()
```

Should I be adding the line `import os` to both the files ?

**How does this impact the performance, supposing there are lots of modules to be imported ? Also, is a module ,once imported, reloaded in this case ?**

Comment: yes.  you are using `os` independently in both modules.

Comment: You can find this out yourself easily: Try running your program when you omit `import os` in one of the files.

Comment: By the way, instead of `my_module.m = myclass(...)`, you should write `m = my_module.myclass(...)`.

Comment: You would have to use `my_module.os..`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each file that you are using a module in, must import that module. Each module is its own namespace. Things you explicitly import within that file are available in that namespace. Thus, if you need `os` in both files, you should import them in both files.