# A file import is working when I run the file from inside the module, but not when I run the file by importing the module from outside

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-module

My directory structure:

```
test.py
module/
    importer.py
    importee.py
    __init__.py
```

So in my directory, I have test.py, then another directory which has been initialized as a module. Within that module, there is a file  importer.py which imports a file importee.py. In order to test whether the import works, I made a simple function in importee.py and tried using it in importer.py (i.e. I ran importer.py directly); it worked just fine.

But when I go into test.py and have the import statement `from module import *` and try to run that (without any other code), it gives an error which traces back to the import statement in importer.py, saying  `No module named 'importee'`

If it matters, the `__init__.py` in the `module` directory has the `__all__` function specified properly.

I like to think this isn't a duplicate despite there being similarly titled posts, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49717533/python-run-part-of-module-only-if-run-from-file-itself-not-when-imported) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51861110/importing-a-module-does-not-run-the-code-inside-it-when-running-a-few-unittest-f) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060724/pytest-return-modulenotfounderror-when-module-imported-in-test-file-import-anoth) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944983/importing-the-same-modules-in-different-files); I've been searching for hours and still have no idea what could be causing this.

Any ideas? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: content of the four files:

init.py

```
__ all __ = ["importee", "importer"]
```

importee.py

```
def example():
    print("hey")
```

importer.py

```
from importee import * 
example()
```

test.py

```
from module import *
```

When I run importer.py I get no errors, but when I run test.py I get a error which traces back to the first line of importer.py saying that `No module named 'importee' found`, even though I don't get that error when running importer.py directly...

Comment: This would be much clearer if you outlined the contents of all four `.py` files (even if you write simplified versions of them)

Comment: @CharlesLandau Apologies, should've done that at first and I've now edited them in.

Answer (score 0):

The following runs and prints "hey" regardless of if you run `python test.py` from root or `python importer.py` from `module`.

You can learn more about relative imports from PEP 328. You can learn more about init [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references), but the important thing I want you to take away from this is that `__init__` runs when you import from `module`.

Furthermore defining `__all__` overrides identifiers that begin with `_`, and since you aren't using them I don't actually know that it would have any effect.

```
# test.py
from module import *
```

---

```
# module/__init__.py
from .importer import *
```

---

```
# module/importee.py
def example():
    print("hey")
```

---

```
# module/importer.py
from .importee import *

example()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm having a bit of trouble understanding. Are you suggesting that I have import statements to every file in my module within my `__init__.py`? Would that do anything? 

Also, the problem was not that I was unable to import the module into test.py, it was that when I imported it for some reason one of the imports used in importer.py (which is *within the module itself*) doesn't work (even though that import works just fine if I run importer.py directly).

Comment: I edited my answer @JamesRonald to hopefully address your question better. You did a good job clarifying